# Convert array of JSON object strings to array of JS objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have some data and I've converted it to an array of objects like:

```
[{"name": "aa", "birth":"19990101"},
{"name": "bb", "birth":"19990102"},
{"name": "cc", "birth":"19990103"}];
```

I want to convert this to an object like this:

```
{"aa":"19990101","bb":"19990102","cc":"19990103"};
```

What would be the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use some destruction and assign the value to the given key.

```js
var array = [{ name: "aa", birth: "19990101" }, { name: "bb", birth: "19990102" }, { name: "cc", birth: "19990103" }],
    object = array.reduce((r, { name, birth }) => (r[name] = birth, r), {});

console.log(object);
```

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
var array = [{ name: "aa", birth: "19990101" }, { name: "bb", birth: "19990102" }, { name: "cc", birth: "19990103" }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array.map(({ name, birth }) => ({ [name]: birth })));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: `(r[name] = birth, r)` is sneaky :)

Comment: Nice usage of destructuring. Noted!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply with `reduce`,

```
var x = [{"name": "aa", "birth":"19990101"},
{"name": "bb", "birth":"19990102"},
{"name": "cc", "birth":"19990103"}];

var result = x.reduce((a, b) => (a[b['name']] = b['birth'], a), {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var a = [{"name": "aa", "birth":"19990101"},
{"name": "bb", "birth":"19990102"},
{"name": "cc", "birth":"19990103"}];

var map = {}; a.forEach( function(item){ map[item.name] = item.birth; })

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be:

```js
var values =[
  {"name": "aa", "birth":"19990101"},
  {"name": "bb", "birth":"19990102"},
  {"name": "cc", "birth":"19990103"}
];

var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var item = {};
    item[values[i].name] = values[i].birth;
    result.push(item);
}

console.log(result);
```